# UIImageView isUserInteractionEnabled = true doesn't work

Tags: swift, uiimageview, isuserinteractionenabled

The following `DateField` class has a date field and an icon on it. For some reason `fieldIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` has zero affect and doesn't pass user tap to the field. Am I missing something?

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

protocol DateFieldDelegate: class {
    func dateSelected(_ dateField: DateField, date: Date)
}

class DateField: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    weak var delegate: DateFieldDelegate?
    let field = UITextField()
    private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?

    convenience init(withStartDate startDate: Date) {
        self.init()

        datePicker = prepareDatePicker()
        guard let datePicker = datePicker else { return }
        field.inputView = datePicker
        field.delegate = self

        addSubview(field)
        field.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(37)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }

        let fieldIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(asset: Asset.calendar))
        field.addSubview(fieldIcon)
        fieldIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true  // doesn't work
        fieldIcon.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(21)
            make.height.equalTo(23)
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        }

        setStyle(.regular)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let date = datePicker?.date else { return }
        field.text = date.formatToString()
        delegate?.dateSelected(self, date: date)
    }

    private func prepareDatePicker() -> UIDatePicker {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.setDate(Date(), animated: false)
        datePicker.locale = Language.appLocale()
        return datePicker
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I've missed something in your code but you need to add some kind of action to the image, enabling `userInteractionEnabled` does not tell it to recognise taps on the item and what to do when this happens. You need to add  a `UITapGestureRecogniser` to the `UIImageView`

```
let fieldIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(asset: Asset.calendar))
field.addSubview(fieldIcon)
fieldIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true  // doesn't work

let fieldIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(asset: Asset.calendar))
field.addSubview(fieldIcon)

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(calenderIconTapped))
fieldIcon.addGestureRecognisor(tapGesture)

func calenderIconTapped() {
    // show the picker
}
```

UPDATE:

After re-reading your question, I understand what your attempting to do now. If you want any taps on the image view to passthrough to the `UITextField` underneath you need to do the opposite of what you tried... you need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` on the `UIImageView`

```
fieldIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: `fieldIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` did not work.
Just to clarify for anyone else; the `fieldIcon` is positioned above the textfield, and I want the tap to go through and activate the textfield.

Comment: that is exactly what `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` should do

Comment: I tried with false, it didn't work. According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled when setting `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` "(the touch event is) removed from the event queue"

`isUserInteractionEnabled = true` works for regular UIViews; there is something about UIImageView that prevents the touch going through to the view underneath.